# Javascript not updating the <input> value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to change the value of an input field using js when clicking a button, but my solution doesn't work at all. I've also tried with the setAttribute('value','My default value'); but didn't work too. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have 3 buttons (+250) (+500) (+1000) and i want that after clicking one of these the input field adds to its value the corresponding value of the button. (IDK if it's helpfull but before all the var there is another function)

```js
var el = document.getElementById("waterInput");
var b250 = document.getElementById("btn250");
var b500 = document.getElementById("btn500");
var b1000 = document.getElementById("btn1000");
var partialWater = 0;

b250.onclick = function() {
  insertInput(250)
}
b500.onclick = function() {
  insertInput(500)
}
b1000.onclick = function() {
  insertInput(1000)
}

function insertInput(water) {
  partialWater += water;
  el.value = toString(partialWater);
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-4">
  <button id="btn250" class="btn btn-outline-primary">+250 ml.</button>
  <button id="btn500" class="btn btn-outline-primary">+500 ml.</button>
  <button id="btn1000" class="btn btn-outline-primary">+1000 ml.</button>
</div>
<form method="post">
  <div class="input-group mb-3" style="width: 50%">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Custom Water" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">ml</span>
  </div>
  <button id="waterInput" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger text-decoration-underline mx-5">Reset</button>
</form>
```

I'm using Flask with pyCharm

Comment: as you are changing text on button control try `el.innerText`

Comment: You have used `waterInput` id on your Add button. Not the `<input>` element. Also use `partialWater.toString()` instead of `toString(partialWater)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help:
put an id to your input (in this case "waterlabel") and pass the value without the toString to el.value

hope this work for you
have a nice day

```js
var el = document.getElementById("waterlabel");
var b250 = document.getElementById("btn250");
var b500 = document.getElementById("btn500");
var b1000 = document.getElementById("btn1000");
var partialWater = 0;

b250.onclick = function() {
  insertInput(250)
}
b500.onclick = function() {
  insertInput(500)
}
b1000.onclick = function() {
  insertInput(1000)
}

function insertInput(water) {
  partialWater += water;
  el.value = partialWater;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-4">
  <button id="btn250" class="btn btn-outline-primary">+250 ml.</button>
  <button id="btn500" class="btn btn-outline-primary">+500 ml.</button>
  <button id="btn1000" class="btn btn-outline-primary">+1000 ml.</button>
</div>
<form method="post">
  <div class="input-group mb-3" style="width: 50%">
    <input id="waterlabel" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Custom Water" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">ml</span>
  </div>
  <button id="waterInput" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger text-decoration-underline mx-5">Reset</button>
</form>
```